# delete from multiple table with inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to delete record from 3 tables in 1 sql query in php. First, I tried it with delete records from two tables. This is the query for that:

```
DELETE pa, pr FROM pollanswers pa INNER JOIN pollresults pr ON
pa.PollQuestionId=pr.PollQuestionId WHERE pa.PollQuestionId = '123';
```

The problem is, what if there is no PollQuestionId in one of these table.. And other thing after that how to integrate it with third table?

Thanks.

Comment: What about accepting correct answer??

Answer (score 3):

You should not delete from multiple tables in one query.

You can define foreign key constraints on the tables with `ON DELETE CASCADE` option.

Then deleting the record from parent table removes the records from child tables.

Check this link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: It'll work in either case.. pollquestion id might not be in any one of the table..

Comment: can you tell me how to join 3 tables?

Comment: Why you want to do it in just one query? Why not do 3 queries?

Comment: By doing it in 3 different queries is not the elegant way to do things. It will take more process time. :)

Comment: It will not take "more" process time... query will delete the same count of records. But you can define foreign key constraints, that will help you...

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out guys.. Thanks for your effort...

here is the query to join 3 tables:

```
DELETE po, pa, pr FROM posts po
LEFT JOIN pollanswers pa ON pa.PollQuestionId=po.PostId
LEFT JOIN pollresults pr ON pr.PollQuestionId=po.PostId
WHERE po.PostId = '123';
```

Comment: This will not work in all cases. And also, only thing you changed is `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`, as I told you first, but also its not correct. F.e.: if there is `PollQuestionId` only in the second table `pollanswers`, it will not work...

Comment: I got your point.. But in my case it's not possible to have pollanswers without postid.

Comment: Can you provide ON DELETE CASCADE with 1 example here. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

To join a third table, you could add another inner join:

```
DELETE pa, pr FROM pollanswers pa
INNER JOIN pollresults pr ON pa.POllQuestionID=pr.PollQuestionId
INNER JOIN pollwhatevers pw ON pw.whatevercolumn=pa.PollquestionID
WHERE pa.PollQuestionId = '123';
```

But if you want to join it to a table that is the result of joining PollResults and PollAnswers, you may want to consider using a temporary table.  See this link for more information,I'm not sure I can explain it as well as this does:

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage7.1/adssql/using_temporary_tables_in_sql_statements.htm